# How to enable Serilog minimum level overrides without particular convention of calling ForContext?

Tags: serilog

[This article on Serilog minimum level overrides](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-minimumlevel-override/) states:

> The first argument of Override is a source context prefix, which is normally matched against the namespace-qualified type name of the class associated with the logger.

For this so-called "normal" behavior, wouldn't I need to manually set the `.ForContext<>()` differently for each class my logger is called from?  In other words, how are namespace-specific minimum log levels supposed to work without a specific convention of how .ForContext is set?

If that makes sense, then how can I set ForContext automatically without calling it with a different argument everywhere?

Answer (score 3):

> For this so-called "normal" behavior, wouldn't I need to manually set
>   the .ForContext<>() differently for each class my logger is called
>   from?

Yes, you would. A common way of doing it is by using the `Log.ForContext<T>()` on each class, in a member variable that gets shared across the different methods of your class (so that all logs get written with the same context). e.g.

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<SomeService>();
    // ...
}

public class SomeRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<SomeRepository>();
    // ...
}
```

If you are using an IoC container such as [Autofac](http://autofac.org), you can have the `.ForContext<>()` call happen automatically when classes are resolved by the IoC container (by using constructor injection, for example).

If you are using [Autofac](http://autofac.org) specifically, you could use [AutofacSerilogIntegration](https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration) that takes care of that. There might be similar implementations for other IoC containers (or you'd have to implement your own).

If you are using Microsoft's Generic Host, then you'll need to configure it to use a custom [`ServiceProviderFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.useserviceproviderfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which will be responsible for creating the instances and making the call to `.ForContext<>()`... An easy route is to [integrate Autofac with Microsoft's Generic Host](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) and then leverage the [AutofacSerilogIntegration](https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration) I mentioned above.

Comment: And if using default Microsoft injection? I'm not sure how to do that, I don't see how to know the type of each consumer in `services.AddTransient`.

Comment: I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost, which appears not to support `UseServiceProviderFactory`.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski The [link I referenced above on Autofac's documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) has examples on how to integrate with ASP .NET Cere

Comment: OK, I migrated to use a generic host.  I'd still like to find a way to do this without Autofac, but not sure what my own ServiceProviderFactory would look like.  All the examples online are related to Autofac.